# Access to all the items

Tags: python, splunk

Using the splunk SDK:

```
kwargs_normalsearch = {"exec_mode": "normal"}
job = service.jobs.create(
    QUERY_,
    **kwargs_normalsearch
    )

while not job.is_done():
    print "."

print "is done: " + str(job.is_done())
print "scanCount: " + str(job["scanCount"])
print "eventCount: " + str(job["eventCount"])
print "resultCount: " + str(job["resultCount"])
```

The result count here is as expected: `877`
However, the below shows only `100` elements

```
results = job.results()
print "are results empty? " + str(results.empty)

reader = splunk_results.ResultsReader(results)
print "Results are a preview: %s" % reader.is_preview
for item in reader:
    print item
```

Here `reader.is_preview` is `None`

How can I get access in the loop to all the items?
Tried without success:

- `results = job.disable_preview()`

Comment: Read about [pagination](http://dev.splunk.com/view/python-sdk/SP-CAAAER5) in the splunk docs, this should help you.

Comment: OK, I see. I did not realize that pagination was the default behavior. Thanks!